# Single and double quotes in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to know exact reason why this error occur playing with quotes.

```
INSERT INTO table_check(name) VALUES('hello'hi') -- ERROR
INSERT INTO table_check(name) VALUES('hello''hi') -- RESULT:- hello'hi
INSERT INTO table_check(name) VALUES('hello'''hi') --ERROR
INSERT INTO table_check(name) VALUES('hello''''hi') --RESULT:- hello''hi
INSERT INTO table_check(name) VALUES('hello'''''hi') --ERROR
INSERT INTO table_check(name) VALUES('hello''''''hi') --RESULT:- hello'''hi
```

Comment: Simple answer is number of single quotes should be a even number else there will be  *Unclosed quotation mark*

Answer (score 5):

Single Quotes are Escaped by Doubling Them up.So whenever even number of  Quotes are present, then we get the Result.

To Know The Behavior of Single Quotes Try to Run This Below Code:

```
Select '','''','''''','''''''',''''''''''
```

So,Single Quotes Should be Even Number Else We get error like:**Unclosed quotation** mark after the character string ') -- ERROR